# What causes late-night hunger in the body?

Tags: nutrition, diet, sleep

Despite eating dinner and making sure to eat a lot, people sometimes still get hungry at night and get "night-munchies" or require a midnight snack. What attributes to this hunger?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Health SE. I am voting to close this question because questions asking for personalised medical adivise are off-topic in this community. However, you may edit this question to make it less personal and I am sure we are looking at an interesting question here.

Comment: @RanaPrathap Oh oh okay.

Comment: What you describe is not hunger. See a doctor.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! Here on Health, we cannot reliably answer this question, as it is a personal medical question. There are too many factors and too much information that we don't have access to, so we can't properly diagnose you. Check out [Are personal medical advice questions on topic here?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/56/are-personal-medical-advice-questions-on-topic-here) or the disclaimer on the sidebar of this page. I would recommend that you see a doctor instead. Thanks :)